# Iterative Deepening Search

Tags: c#

How can I create an instance of the Tree in Main method and traverse it using this algorithm?

I can't find how to bypass class and IComparable constraints here because it doesn't accept my custom key and value classes or any other prebuilt collection and Im getting "There's no implicit conversion from
IterativeDeepeningSearch.Key to 'System.IComparable<IterativeDeepeningSearch.Key>'".

"IterativeDeepeningSearch" is the name of the namespace name.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Tree<K, V>
     where K : class, IComparable<K>
     where V : class
    {
        private Node<K, V> root;

        /// <summary>
        /// Searches tree using BFS but the depth of the search
        /// is limited. Level of root is 0.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="root">To start the search</param>
        /// <param name="goal"></param>
        /// <param name="depth">Maximum depth of level to search</param>
        /// <returns>Default of V if key is not found</returns>
        public V DepthLimitedSearch(Node<K, V> root, K goal, int depth)
        {
            if (depth == 0 && root.key == goal)
            {
                return root.value;
            }
            else if (depth > 0)
            {
                foreach (var child in root.children)
                {
                    var result = DepthLimitedSearch(child, goal, depth - 1);
                    if (result != default(V))
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
                return default(V);
            }
            else
            {
                return default(V);
            }
        }

        public V IterativeDeepeningSearch(K key, int depth)
        {
            for (int currentDepth = 0; currentDepth <= depth; currentDepth++)
            {
                var v = DepthLimitedSearch(root, key, currentDepth);
                if (v != default(V))
                {
                    return v;
                }
            }
            return default(V);
        }

        public class Node<K, V>
            where K : class, IComparable<K>
            where V : class
        {
            public K key;
            public V value;
            public Node<K, V>[] children;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/sXte4h. Or is this another class `IterativeDeepeningSearch.Key` which does not implement `IComparable`? There some other things wrong: you need to change `root.key == goal` to `root.key.Equals(goal)`. And if you nest `Node` inside `Tree<K, V>` then you shouldn't redeclare `K` and `V` on `Node`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've ended up changing it entirely and used a new algorithm.